# tsql to find members not contacted in past 18 months

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, subquery, window-functions

I have a table that has ContactNumber (Bigint), MemberNumber(bigInt) and ContactDate(date).

The table has millions of records (sample data image attached). I want to get all the records where member has not been contacted for last 18 months. How do I do that using tsql?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Can you share the error message your SQL produced?

Comment: The likelihood of you getting a good answer goes up if you read and adhere to these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a Member table containing all your members, right? Assuming you do, just select all the members that don't have contact in the last 18 months.

```
SELECT *
FROM Member m
LEFT JOIN Contacts c on m.MemberNumber = c.MemberNumber AND
  c.ContactDate > DATEADD(Month, -18, GETDATE())
WHERE c.ContactNumber IS NULL
```

I believe this would work too.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Member m
WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM   Contacts
    WHERE  MemberNumber = m.MemberNumber
            AND ContactDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -18, GETDATE())
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all the records where member has not been contacted for last 18 months.

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.MemberNumber = t.MemberNumber 
        and t1.ContactDate >= dateadd(month, -18, cast(getdate() as date))
)
```

With an index on `(MemberNumber, ContactDate)`, this should be rather efficient.

Another option is to use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, max(ContactDate) over(partition by MemberNumber) maxContactDate
    from mytable t
) t
where maxContactDate < dateadd(month, -18, cast(getdate() as date))
```